# Parameters naming in jQuery Post?

Tags: jquery, servlets, post

I'm creating a form builder. I'm trying to save a the HTML of a form to the server. I will then get this html in a get to rebuild the form

So i am attempting to send a jQuery object (html of a form) to a servlet like so.

```
var savedForm= $('#resultsFormCont').html();
    $.post('http://localhost:8080/BootStrapForms/NewServlet',
                {savedForm : savedForm} 
                ,function(data ){ //callback on success
        alert('Form Saved' + data);
    })
```

but in my doPost method below retuns null?. Any Ideas?

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        formHTML = request.getParameter("savedForm");
        System.out.println("form is " + formHTML);
}
```

Comment: **Why** are you sending HTML to the server? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm creating a form builder. I'm trying to save a the HTML of a form to the server. I will then get this html in a get to rebuild the form.

Comment: Might be better to implement something that takes the form itself and breaks down the elements into relevant info: id, name, value, classes, type, etc. Then send that info (probably as a JSON string) to the server, and save that. Then have something that goes the other way when you need to rebuild the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post('http://localhost:8080/BootStrapForms/NewServlet',{savedForm : savedForm} .....`
POST's it to the server as savedForm

Although as @Anthony Grist said, why you want to send html in a POST request is a different matter entirely

Comment: `formHTML = request.getParameter("savedForm");`